# How can I stop 2 different playing audio at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift

How can I stop 2 different playing audio at the same time? When music is playing, another button pressed playing it's audio at the same time. Sorry for my english.

`NoiseMaker`:

```
import AVFoundation

class NoiseMaker {
    let audioFileNames = ["guitar", "applause", "monster", "bubbles"]
    let players: [AVAudioPlayer?]

    init() {
        players = audioFileNames.map { filename in
            if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(filename, withExtension: "wav") {
                return try? AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    func play(index: Int) {
        if !players.isEmpty && index >= 0 && index < players.count {
            players[index]?.play()
        }
    }
}
```

`ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let noiseMaker = NoiseMaker()

    @IBAction func playSound(sender: UIButton) {
        noiseMaker.play(sender.tag)
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post links to the code, use code tags and put your code right in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an instance variable for the currently playing sound. When you tap a button, send a stop message to the currently playing sound, copy the new sound to the instance variable, and then start that sound playing.

Comment: I did not do it

Comment: "I did not do it." What is that supposed to mean? You didn't try what I suggested? You tried it but you could not get it to work?

Comment: i can not to execute. i am weak for realize